# Not able to make the value types inside a structure as mutable in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, struct, mutable, immutable-collections

I am converting VB6 codes to C# Here I have to convert array of struct into List approach in c# but not able to modify the value in the below sample code getting error as 
"Cannot modify the return value of `System.Collections.Generic.List<test.Program.TagFieldValue>.this[int]`because it is not a variable".

What am I doing wrong.. Is there any other way to do it without converting my type to class?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        private struct TagFieldValue
        {
            private int _ID;
            public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }
        }

        private List<TagFieldValue> mFieldValues = new List<TagFieldValue>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.test();
        }

        public void test()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                TagFieldValue temp = new TagFieldValue();
                temp.ID = i;                
                mFieldValues.Add(temp);                
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                mFieldValues[i].ID = mFieldValues[i].ID + 10;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mFieldValues[i].ID);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @john Unfortunately that comment is not accurate. Structs are not immutable by virtue of being a struct (though most advice says they should be to promote a better style of programming against them), they are value types. In this instance, the struct is mutable, but the issue is that a copy is being mutated and then immediately binned.

Answer (score 2):

`Structs` are passed as value, not reference. `mFieldValues[i].ID = mFieldValues[i].ID + 10;` will modify the copy in the list, not the `struct` itself. To modify the value in the list you need to create new `TagFieldValue`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    mFieldValues[i] = new TagFieldValue { ID = mFieldValues[i].ID + 10 };
}
```

Or change `TagFieldValue` to `class`

```
private class TagFieldValue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What this is actually doing is taking a copy of the struct at various points, but the salient occasion is `mFieldValues[i].ID  = `. An alternative to creating a new one, because in this instance the struct is not immutable, is to grab a copy, make the change, and copy back into the array: `var s = mFieldValues[i]; s.ID = s.ID + 10; mFieldValues[i] = s;`

Comment: The current implementation contains many structures and most of them are used in VB6 as Array of structure, so here i have made them in C# as List <mystructure> .. if i start to convert each structure into a class code will become less readable and maintenance will be a problem but at the same time editing the value each time in many places as mentioned above doesn't look good either. Pls give some suggestions on this.

Comment: @user3816092 Not entirely sure how you think it will be less readable and maintainable - those are not negative qualities of classes, just poor code.

Answer (score 0):

Structs aren't that flexible. the inputs can't be defined either, so if you want to do this, you should use a class instead. I had a similar problem and changing it to a class did not give any problems.